How to write cmake file for hybrid mpi and openmp
How to include MPI and OpenMP compiler in the CMake file?
I tried to include the following lines:
#this find out compilers for mpi 
find_package(MPI REQUIRED)

#this find out compilers for openmp
find_package(OpenMP)

Then I link to both libraries:
target_link_libraries(mympiopenmpproject PUBLIC MPI::MPI_CXX PUBLIC OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX)

Here is my test code:
void openmp_run ()
{
   
    
    double t0, t1;
    t0 = MPI_Wtime();
    #pragma omp parallel for
        for(std::size_t zindex=1; zindex<100000; zindex++)
           {
              //do something here
           }      

    t1 = MPI_Wtime(); 

    std::cout <<" Multithread wall clock: "<< std::scientific 
                << t1-t0<<std::endl;
}

Then I run the code
mpirun -n 16 -x OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 ./test

The computational time is about 4.933536e-02
If I run with less number of threads:
mpirun -n 16 -x OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 ./test

I got similar time.
Why is this the case using different number of threads for each cpu?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You could first do a basic check by printing out thread numbers (omp_get_thread_num() using a function from the OpenMP runtime API is also a good way of checking if CMake properly links the OpenMP runtime library) to see if threads are created. If threads are created, there remains the question what hardware you are running on (are there enough cores) and what kind of work you are running on them (are you e.g. limited by memory bandwidth). I.e. there still isn't enough information in the question.

what if you run in singleton mode (e.g. OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 ./test) does the time decrease when you increase the number of OpenMP threads?

You can check the output of make VERBOSE=1 to check that your code is built with the appropriate OpenMP flag

Hi, in the link.txt, I could see that /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi_cxx.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openmpi/lib/libmpi.so /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12/libgomp.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.a.

What flag I shall see for the openMP in building ?

I am now using one cpu, with different number of threads:  1-threads 1.97s,  2-threads 1.63s, 3-threads  1.73s, 4-threads 1.78s, 5-threads 1.83s. It seems increasing number of threads does not decrease the computational cost.

I got correct thread numbering by calling omp_get_thread_num():  1.836830e+00s in threads 0; 1.836830e+00s in threads 1;  1.836830e+00s in threads 2;  1.836830e+00s in threads 3. It is interesting to obverse the same computational time for all threads. I thought it might be slightly different from one thread to another...

try to export KMP_AFFINITY=compact,verbose to make sure you do not end up time sharing.

The problem seems solved, I have to call
mpirun --bind-to none -np 4 ./test
I have forget to use --bind-to none, but I am not totally sure, why
--bind-to none
matters..
